# Compile time only dependency and ProGuard using Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard, android-library

I am building an Android library with Gradle and I have a compile time only dependency.

I am using Gradle 0.9+ so if I do

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.packageLibrary.exclude( 'libs/libA.jar' )
}
```

it works and libA.jar is not packaged in my final aar.

However, if I turn ProGuard to on, this does not work and libA.jar is getting packaged.

I have also excluded this jar from obfuscation by adding

```
-keep class com.libA.** { *; }
```

to my proguard-rules.txt but it doesn't make any difference.

I can see that the `proguardRelease` task gets executed before all the `packageRelease` tasks, however I am not really sure if I can do anything.

This is my whole build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.packageLibrary.exclude( 'libs/libA.jar' )
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

Is there any way to compile against a jar but exclude it from the final package without having to turn ProGuard off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently came back to this and found a workaround, so I thought I would share:

I am now adding the 'libs' folder as a local repository, so my build file looks something like that (I have also updated the Gradle version):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ':libA'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

The dependency is resolved fine and is not packaged in the final aar.

Also, I am not including anything extra in the proguard file.